# Linear independence under a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ u_1,u_2 $ be linearly independent elements of $U$. There is a linear map $T:U \to V$. Given this $T(u_1), T(u_2)$ are a linearly independent elements of $V$. Here, $U$ and $V$ are vector spaces over a field $K$.

My attempt:

$a_1u_1+a_2u_2=0_U$

(*) $T(a_1u_1+a_2u_2)=T(0_U)$

(*) is equivalent to,

(**): $a_1T(u_1)+a_2T(u_2)=T(0_U)=0_V$

We know $a_1=a_2=0$ as $u_1, u_2$ is a linearly independent set

Suppose $a_3,a_4$ are also solutions to (**)

Then $ T^{-1}( a_3T(u_1)+a_4T(u_2))=T^{-1}(0_V) $

This means $ a_3(u_1)+a_4(u_2)=(0_U) $, but this is not possible as $u_1,u_2$ are linearly independent

So $a_1,a_2$ are the only solutions to (**) $\Rightarrow$ linear independence.

**a) Have I made any oversights/mistakes in my attempted proof? b)Can someone direct me towards proving this statement is true/false?**

Comment: You seem to be missing half of the problem statement.  Check to make sure that everything is written correctly.  For instance, do we know anything more about $T$ such as it being injective?  You refer to $T^{-1}$, why should that exist?

Comment: As it is written, it sounds like you are trying to prove that $u_1,u_2$ being linearly independent vectors in a vector space $U$ and $T$ being a linear transformation from a vector space $U$ to a vector space $V$ that you want to try to prove that $T(u_1)$ is linearly independent of $T(u_2)$.  That statement as written is false... Consider the trivial map which maps everything to the zero vector.  You would have $T(u_1)=T(u_2)=0$ and these are clearly not linearly independent of one another.

Comment: it seems that the statement is: **if $T(u_1)$ and $T(u_2)$ are linearly independent then $u_1$ and $u_2$ are also linearly independent.**  Is it that the case @palt34?

Comment: The other way around if $u_1 and u_2$ is a linearly independent set of U then $T(u_1), T(u_2$)$ is a linearly independent set of V. T is a linear map from U to V

Comment: I believe @JMoravitz, gave me an example for which this does not hold, is there a more rigorous way of disproving this?

Comment: "*Is there a more rigorous way of disproving something (than by counterexample)?*"  Disproof by counterexample is perfectly rigorous... what more do you expect?

Comment: a simple example serves that, as JMoravitz said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true. Let $V =\mathbb R$, and let $T:U\to \mathbb R$ be any linear map. It doesn't matter what $u_1,u_2\in U$ you choose, $T(u_1),T(u_2)$ will always be linearly dependent because $\mathbb R$ has dimension $1$: It's impossible to find two or more linearly independent vectors of $\mathbb R$.

---

On the other hand, if $T:U\to V$ is injective, and if $T(u_1),T(u_2)$ are linearly dependent, then there exists $\alpha,\beta$ such that:

$$\alpha T(u_1)+\beta T(u_2)=0_V$$
$$\iff T(\alpha u_1+\beta u_2)=0_V$$
$$\iff \alpha u_1+\beta u_2\in \ker (T)$$

But, because $T$ is injective, $\ker(T)=\{0_U\}$. This means that $$\alpha u_1+\beta u_2=0_U$$

So, in other words $T(u_1),T(u_2)$ are linearly dependent $\implies$ $u_1,u_2$ are linearly dependent

This is the same as saying: $u_1,u_2$ are linearly independent $\implies $ $T(u_1),T(u_2)$ are linearly independent (Contraposition)

So in the case where $T$ is injective, that holds.